# Are weak* topology and strong topology the same in $L^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, R)$ be a reference probability space.
For short, we use $\mathbb E[\cdot]$ to denote the expectation operator
 $\mathbb E^{R}[\cdot]$ under probability $R$.
We consider the following two layers of function spaces.

The lower level function space is $L^{1}$, the collection of
 $\mathcal F$-measurable integrable random variables $X$ with 
 endowed with norm $\|X\|_{1} = \mathbb E[|X|].$

The upper level function space is $L^{\infty}$, that is the collection
of all random variables 
$X$ with $\hbox{esssup}_{\Omega} |X| <\infty$, 
endowed with weak* topology, which is equivalent to the norm induced by
$$\|\phi\|_{*} = \sup\{ \mathbb E[ \phi X] : \mathbb E[X] \le 1\}.$$

Compared weak* norm in $L^{\infty}$, one can define
 different norm by 
$$\|\phi\|_{\infty} = \hbox{esssup} |\phi|.$$ 
We refer weak* topology and strong topology in $L^{\infty}$ induced
by $\|\cdot\|_{*}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$, respectively. Now we have
two opposite claims.

[Claim 1.] First, 
$\| \cdot\|_{*}$ and $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ should be different 
norms in $L^{\infty}$. This can be seen from the following fact:
The closed unit ball $B^{*}(1) = \{\phi: \|\phi\|_{*} \le 1 \}$ is compact under
weak* topology by Alaoglu's theorem, while the closed unit ball 
$B^{\infty}(1) = \{\phi: \|\phi\|_{\infty} \le 1\}$ is not compact under $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$.

[Claim 2.] Second, we can show that
$\|\phi\|_{*} = \|\phi\|_{\infty}$ for all $\phi \in L^{\infty}$ as follows.
One direction is straightforward: 
$$\|\phi\|_{*} = \sup\{ \mathbb E[ \phi X] : \mathbb E[X] \le 1\}
\le \|\phi\|_{\infty} \sup\{ \mathbb E[ X] : \mathbb E[X] \le 1\}
= \|\phi\|_{\infty}.$$
The other direction is to show $\|\phi\|_{*} \ge \|\phi\|_{\infty}$.
For arbitrary $\phi \in L^{\infty}$, set $$A_{n} = \{\omega\in \Omega:
\phi(\omega) \ge \|\phi\|_{*} + 1/n\}.$$ If $R(A_{n}) >0$, then with indicator
$I_{A_{n}}$, we have the following contradiction:
$$\|\phi\|_{*} \ge \mathbb E[\phi R^{-1}(A_{n}) I_{A_{n}}] \ge \|\phi\|_{*} + 1/n.
$$
This implies $R(A_{n}) = 0$ for all $n>0$ and hence $\phi \le \|\phi\|_{*}$ almost surely in $R$. This implies the other direction.

[Q.] Can you indicate which one is false among two opposite claims?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite true that $\|\cdot\|_\ast = \|\cdot\|_\infty$.  The problem is that   the norm $\|\cdot\|_\ast$ does not induce the weak-* topology.

For an explicit example, take $\Omega = [0,1]$ with $R$ Lebesgue measure.  Let $\phi_n = 1_{(0, 1/n)}$.  It follows from the dominated convergence theorem that $E[\phi_n X] \to 0$ for any $X \in L^1(R)$, so $\phi_n \to 0$ in the weak-* topology.  But clearly we have $\|\phi_n\|_\ast = \|\phi_n\|_\infty = 1$ for every $n$.

In fact, except in trivial cases (where $L^1(R)$ and $L^\infty(R)$ are finite dimensional), the weak-* topology is not induced by *any* norm.  For instance, it is not first countable.

Comment: Thanks so quick response. Then, how does one define unit ball in $L^\infty$ under weak* topology? (wiki) Banach–Alaoglu theorem (also known as Alaoglu's theorem) states that the closed unit ball of the dual space of a normed vector space is compact in the weak* topology.

Comment: Alaoglu's theorem is about the weak* topology on the norm unit ball.  Since there is no metric for the weak* topology (or for the weak topology), we just say "unit ball" for the norm unit ball.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for the clarification.